# DL140 G3 HP Embedded SATA RAID Controller, max 750 GB drives. Really?

Tags: hp-proliant, sata

I have a DL140 G3 and according to [HP's documentation](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12509_na/12509_na.HTML) the max capacity SATA drive I can put on the HP Embedded SATA RAID Controller is 2x750GB. If I put a 2TB drive in here will something terrible happen?

Comment: probably because when the DL140 G3 came out, 750GB was the largest drive they had tested and certified.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work for you? Please provide an answer.

Answer (score 3):

For those who want the answer. Mine run with a 1.5Tb in driveA and a 2Tb in driveB.
Both sata disks are working very well.

Answer (score 2):

If it says it only supports up to 750 GB, the worst thing that can happen is probably it not recognizing the drive.

Comment: Yeah... Guess I should just test it out. Thanks Lucas.